# Sorting by month-year groups by month instead

Tags: python, sorting, date, text

I have a curious python problem.

The script takes two csv files, one with a column of dates and the other a column of text snippets. in the other excel file there is a bunch of names (substrings).
All that the code does is step through both lists building up a name-mentioned-per-month matrix.

- FILE with dates and text: (Date, Snippet first column)
- ENTRY 1 : Sun 21 nov 2014 etc,    The release of the iphone 7 was...

-**strings file**

- iphone 7
- apple
- apples
- innovation etc.

The problem is that when i try to order it so that the columns follow in asceding order, e.g. oct-2014, nov-2014, dec-2014 and so on, it just groups the months together instead, which isn't what i want

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime


file_1 = input('Enter first CSV name (one with the date and snippet): ')
file_2 = input('Enter second CSV name (one with the strings): ')
outp = input('Enter the output CSV name: ')


file_1_list = []
head = True
for row in csv.reader(open(file_1, encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')):
    if head:
        head = False
        continue
    date = datetime.strptime(row[0].strip(), '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y')
    date_str = date.strftime('%b %Y')
    file_1_list.append([date_str, row[1].strip()])

file_2_dict = {}

for line in csv.reader(open(file_2, encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')):
    s = line[0].strip()
    for d in file_1_list:
        if s.lower() in d[1].lower():
            if s in file_2_dict.keys():
                if d[0] in file_2_dict[s].keys():
                    file_2_dict[s][d[0]] += 1
                else:
                    file_2_dict[s][d[0]] = 1
            else:
                file_2_dict[s] = {
                    d[0]: 1
                }

months = []
for v in file_2_dict.values():
    for k in v.keys():
        if k not in months:
            months.append(k)
months.sort()

rows = [[''] + months]

for k in file_2_dict.keys():
    tmp = [k]
    for m in months:
        try:
            tmp.append(file_2_dict[k][m])
        except:
            tmp.append(0)
    rows.append(tmp)
print("still working on it be patient")
writer = csv.writer(open(outp, "w", encoding='utf-8', newline=''))
for r in rows:
    writer.writerow(r)

print('Done...')
```

From my understanding I am months.sort() isnt doing what i expect it to?
I have looked here , where they apply some other function to sort the data, using attrgetter,

```
from operator import attrgetter

>>> l = [date(2014, 4, 11), date(2014, 4, 2), date(2014, 4, 3), date(2014, 4, 8)]
```

and then

```
sorted(l, key=attrgetter('month'))
```

But I am not sure whether that would work for me?
From my understanding I parse the dates 12-13, am I missing an order data first, like

```
data = sorted(data, key = lambda row: datetime.strptime(row[0], "%b-%y"))
```

I have only just started learning python and so many things are new to me i dont know what is right and what isnt?

[image: What is outputted]
What I want(of course with the correctly sorted data):
[image: Ordered by increasing month-year (data of course sorted along with the dates)]

Comment: Can u add example of desired output row to input rows?

Comment: See above please

Answer (score 0):

This took a while because you had so much unrelated stuff about reading csv files and finding and counting tags. But you already have all that, and it should have been completely excluded from the question to avoid confusing people.

It looks like your actual question is "How do I sort dates?"

Of course "Apr-16" comes before "Oct-14", didn't they teach you the alphabet in school? A is the first letter! I'm just being silly to emphasize a point -- it's because they are simple strings, not dates.

You need to convert the string to a date with the datetime class method strptime, as you already noticed. Because the class has the same name as the module, you need to pay attention to how it is imported. You then go back to a string later with the member method strftime on the actual datetime (or date) instance.

Here's an example:

```
from datetime import datetime

unsorted_strings = ['Oct-14', 'Dec-15', 'Apr-16']
unsorted_dates = [datetime.strptime(value, '%b-%y') for value in unsorted_strings]
sorted_dates = sorted(unsorted_dates)
sorted_strings = [value.strftime('%b-%y') for value in sorted_dates]

print(sorted_strings)
```

> ['Oct-14', 'Dec-15', 'Apr-16']

or skipping to the end

```
from datetime import datetime
unsorted_strings = ['Oct-14', 'Dec-15', 'Apr-16']
print (sorted(unsorted_strings, key = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%b-%y')))
```

> ['Oct-14', 'Dec-15', 'Apr-16']